# svn Access forbidden

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a user who is getting "access forbidden" errors when attempting to execute nearly any operation with the server.

Interestingly, the problem disappeared when, instead of accessing the server through the alias (defined in my local "hosts" file, I aimed a checkout at the ip address of the server.  In that case, I had to accept the certificate and I was in business.

Earlier in the process I had deleted the contents of the subversion "auth" folder in an attempt to force credentials.  The problem is persisting, however.  I thought that by deleting servers.ssl from the auth folders, I might clear a permanent rejection which might have taken place.

Anywhere else to look?

Toitoise svn, sliksvn, Windows10

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the "access forbidden" message was symptomatic of attempting to use the proxy server on our corporate network.  Adding a few lines to %APPDATA%/subversion/servers got the job done.